# Is Google Pagespeed Insights reliable

Tags: pagespeed

I am working on one website, to optimize the performance.

I had, according to Pagespeed Insights (https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/?) a Server Response time of 1.7s.

After some work, Lighthouse (embedded in Chrome) gives me a Server Response time of 200ms, my page is noticeably faster. But Pagespeed insights still gives me results in the 1.5s range.

Which one should I trust?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Google PageSpeed uses a “combo” of **lab** and **real-world data**, whereas Lighthouse uses **lab data only**  to build its report. Since lighthouse is integrated into PSI for sake of consistency you should trust PSI over just lab data.